# Angular Cypress how to get elements which has got dynamic ids

Tags: angular, cypress

I am completely new to E2E with Cypress. I have a table with dynamic rows. I want to shift+select particular column in all the rows and copy paste a value.

Can anyone help me how to get the dynamic element. in this example i have 108 rows and i want to select 3rd column of each row. The column has to following id. and i want to change value 'No' to 'Yes' in this example.

```
<div class="wj-cell wj-alt wj-wrap editable-cell" tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" aria-required="true" id="catRatingImportManualInputRow105Col3" style="left: 610px; top: 3485px; width: 155px; height: 33px;">
    <button class="wj-btn wj-btn-glyph wj-right wj-elem-dropdown" type="button" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Toggle Dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="wj-glyph-down"></span>
    </button>
    No
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html) to loop through your table in cypress. to access the third element you can use the [index value](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Arguments).

Since your id is `catRatingImportManualInputRow105Col3` is dynamic, so we will use only use the part of your id that is static, so your css selector should be something like: `div[id*="catRatingImportManualInputRow"]`

```
cy.get('div[id*="catRatingImportManualInputRow"]').each(($ele, index) => {
    if (index == 2)
        //Do something with the third element
        cy.wrap($ele).click().type('Yes')
})
```